# Python Pandas OneHotEncoder categories

Tags: python, pandas

I was reading about One Hot Encoding in Python and there is a line that I cannot explain what it means. The code is the following:

```
ohe=preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(dtype=np.int,sparse=True,handle_unknown="ignore")
data=ohe.fit_transform(df[["country"]])
```

The thing is when I print the values of categories like this:

```
print (ohe.categories_)
```

It prints `[array(['EEUU', 'France', 'Portugal', 'Italy'], dtype=object)]`

but when I do this:

```
print (ohe.categories_[0])

['EEUU', 'France', 'Portugal', 'Italy']
```

I was not able to found what does that [0] does, it seems that it converts from an array to a list, but why not use something like the tolist() function?

I have searched on the web, but I was not able to find an explanation about this expression, any help?

Thanks

Comment: Try  encode a dataframe with more than one column, something like `data=ohe.fit_transform(df[["country", "province"]])`  - You then will see more than one array. Note that the print starts with a left bracket  `[array([ ...]` which indicates its a list of arrays.

Comment: `categories_` is a list, so `categories_[0]` is just the first element in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[array(['EEUU', 'France', 'Portugal', 'Italy'], dtype=object)]` is a list with one object. This object is a numpy array. When you do `ohe.categories_[0]`, you access the first item of this list - which happens to be the only item in the list.

`ohe.categories_` returns a list because it returns a different `numpy` array for each column in your input. Since `df[["country"]]` has only one column, it returns a list with only one object.

If you did `df[["country", "second_column"]]`, for instance, you'd get a list with two arrays, stating categories for each.